# Pluralization bug in "show more comments" and "load new answers" button

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, live-refresh, plurals

As of very recently, pluralization bugs have appeared in the system. I could have sworn that these used to look correctly; it seems like a very recent change has caused this bug.

When someone posts a comment, and it's loaded in someone else's browser by the heartbeat, it used to properly show "show 1 more comment", but it now shows "show 1 more comments".

> [image: show 1 more comments]

Also, when someone posts a new answer, it used to show "1 new answer to this question", but now it shows "1 new answers to this question". I don't have a screenshot for this, but I could have sworn it used to display correctly earlier.

Is this a side effect of the recent change that caused server errors on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reproduce:

[image: show 1 more comment]

[image: 1 new answer to this question]

Comment: How is your machine showing a pipe symbol between "add a comment" and "show [x] more comments"?