# Pluralization issue when only one more comment is to be shown: "Show 1 more comments"

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, plurals

Below, the "Show X more comments" link has been capitalized, and a pluralization error has been introduced:

[image: "Show 1 more comments"]

It wasn't like that before (the grammar, I mean), so can we fix it?

Comment: A [previous duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316334/282094), but it's closed [status-norepro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plurals+comments+status-norepro) by the author.

Comment: I'm getting the plural too.

Comment: @Rob Good, glad it's not just me.

Comment: Easy fix will be to change the wording to: "Show more comments (1)", i.e. having the number of new comment(s) in brackets after the message.

Comment: Anyway, SE started to [mark plural bugs as by design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZpiM.png) without explaining, so I'm afraid you're wasting your time reporting such bugs. (that's the reason I stopped reporting such bugs)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Bugger.

Comment: This seems to be a problem not specific to Stack Exchange. Isn't there a Stack Overflow question we can point the Stack Overflow developers to? Why isn't there a single central place (library, code generation, or similar) that takes care of if it (instead of inline formatting)? Hasn't a solution been developed in the last 12 years?

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating this also applies to the "1 users have bookmarked this question" tooltip, for the record.

Comment: @Ollie it's everywhere, always was, and always will - difference is that judging by the responses we get recently (or don't get, only cold retagging with status declined or by design), they won't bother fixing it anymore. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating The new status-planned tag may tell a different story ;)

Comment: I'd argue... if there's only one additional comment, show it, don't hide till there's 2 or more to hide.

Comment: @Ollie so maybe it applies only to winter bash. Still, can take 6-8 weeks/months to be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed.

[image]

> "Pluralization"
> is hard to use in haiku
> syllables galore